# Why does Perl have separate operators for testing string equality and numeric equality?

Tags: perl

In Perl, why are there separate operators for string comparison (`eq`, `ne`) vs. numeric comparison (`==`, `!=`)? Why use two separate sets of operators instead of using a single operator for both string and numeric comparisons?

Comment: It has these operators so it doesn't have to reinvent the wheel with `===` and `!==` operators, which btw doesn't quite solve the comparison problem.

Comment: Perl has different operators for numeric and string comparison because numeric and string comparison are different operations. Better to ask, why do so many other languages use one operator for dissimilar things, even the ones without a type system that would make it unambiguous?

Comment: Short answer: **Because Perl doesn't know if a value is a number or not.** To Perl, the numeric value `2` can be just as easily be stored as a string as it be stored as a signed int.

Comment: Compare this to Javascript where, say, the `+` operator is defined to do different things on strings and numbers, and the annoyance and confusion that causes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl does automatic type conversion whenever it feels like it to evaluate an expression. This requires two operators so the programmer can distinguish between string and numeric comparisons:

```
print "eq" if "02" eq "2"; # string comparison -- no output
print "==" if "02" == "2"; # numeric comparison -- will print "=="
```

The above was taken from [this thread on PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=276020). Here's some other info from that thread:

- One reason to use `==` rather than `eq` is so that you can get warnings if something non-numerical is used where you expect a number.
- One reason to use `eq` rather than `==` is that string conversions lose a few decimal places, so you put off hitting spurious inequalities due to floating-point rounding errors.
- Consider writing `2 == $val` rather than `$val == 2`. It looks odd, but that way the common typo of `=` rather than `==` will give you an immediate compilation error rather than a nasty bug.

Comment: string conversions do not lose a few decimal places, they lose a partial decimal place.

Comment: (e.g. a 64-bit floating point number with a 53-bit significand can store numbers with a precision of 15.9 decimal digits but we stringify it to 15 decimal digits)

Comment: [Warnings will catch that last case before it becomes a nasty bug](https://eval.in/202162), but that is a clever way of transforming a runtime warning to a compiletime error (at the cost of a slightly less explanatory error message, which [omits the most salient part of the error](https://eval.in/202163) (the `2 = `).

Comment: @ysth - Yes, good point. I was just quoting. :)